# Spring MVC: Understanding of view binding

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I try to create pdf view according this [tutorial](https://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-mvc-export-data-to-pdf-file-via-abstractpdfview/)

I have `controller`:

```
@Controller
public class UserController {

    @Autowired
    UserDao userDao;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/user_pdf", method = RequestMethod.GET, headers = "Accept=application/pdf")
    public ModelAndView usersPdf(@ModelAttribute("model") ModelMap model) {
        return new ModelAndView("pdfView", "listBooks", userDao.getAll());
    }
}
```

I have `servlet configuration`:

```
    <context:component-scan base-package="ua.epam.spring.hometask" />
<context:annotation-config/>

<bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.freemarker.FreeMarkerViewResolver">
    <property name="cache" value="true"/>
    <!--<property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/ftl"/>-->
    <property name="suffix" value=".ftl"/>
</bean>

<bean id="freemarkerConfig" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.freemarker.FreeMarkerConfigurer">
    <property name="templateLoaderPath" value="/WEB-INF/ftl/"/>
</bean>

<bean id="PdfRevenueSummary"
      class="ua.epam.spring.hometask.view.UserPdfView">
</bean>
```

And I have `pdf builder`:

```
@Component
public class UserPdfView extends AbstractPdfView {

    protected void buildPdfDocument(Map model,
                                    Document document, PdfWriter writer, HttpServletRequest req,
                                    HttpServletResponse resp) throws Exception {

        User user = (User) model.get("command");

        Paragraph header = new Paragraph(new Chunk("Generate Pdf USing Spring Mvc",FontFactory.getFont(FontFactory.HELVETICA, 30)));
        Paragraph by = new Paragraph(new Chunk("Author " + user.getFirstName() + " " + user.getLastName(),FontFactory.getFont(FontFactory.HELVETICA, 20)));

        document.add(header);
        document.add(by);

    }

}
```

Surely I made appropriate `<servlet-mapping>` in `web.xml`

**Questions:**

1. How does binding work? From the tutorial I see that there is now linkage from `Controller` to `PDF view`
2. Please, help me to see how to fix my code. I see `404 error code` now, and when I remove `headers = "Accept=application/pdf"` I see it tries to resolve it with `FreeMarkerViewResolver`

Comment: `ModelAndView` inserts a Model object into a Template View, therefore allowing access in the template to bind to the model data. What do you not understand about that?

Comment: I have also `FreeMarkerViewResolver`. I don't understand how `Spring` decides which `viewresolver` to choose

Comment: Anything that ends in the FTL extension goes to the first viewResolver that in matches in the servlet config

Comment: And how does `Spring` decide I want pdf? By header `Accept=application/pdf`?

Comment: Makes sense to me, but you'd have to find the source code to determine that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Accept` header should be specified by the client (i.e. browser). `@RequestMapping` annotation should specify corresponding `produces` attribute to match the request. Basically, the annotation should look like this to match a request with `Accept=application/pdf`

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/user_pdf", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "application/pdf")
```

To test that method use something like [postman](https://www.getpostman.com/) specifying `Accept` header.

In order to get your pdf view resolved you want to configure a view resolver. In the tutorial it is this part (missing in your snippets):

```
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.XmlViewResolver">
   <property name="location">
      <value>/WEB-INF/spring-pdf-views.xml</value>
   </property>
</bean>
```

This bean declares that you have a `/WEB-INF/spring-pdf-views.xml` file that contains a configuration for beans responsible for views. However you can configure `BeanNameViewResolver` to avoid creating additional file (less flexible solution but choice is your):

```
<bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.BeanNameViewResolver"/>
```

Take care to return the exact same view name in controller method as view-bean id (now they are inconsistent). Since

```
<bean id="PdfRevenueSummary" class="ua.epam.spring.hometask.view.UserPdfView"/>
```

you are supposed to return

```
return new ModelAndView("PdfRevenueSummary", "listBooks", userDao.getAll());
```

Another issue with your example is that probably the bean of `UserPdfView` class gets instantiated twice: it is declared in xml configuration and maybe picked up by component scan because of `@Component` annotation.

Comment: Thanks for answer! It makes things clear. But anyway I get exception `javax.servlet.ServletException: Could not resolve view with name 'pdfView' in servlet with name 'user_pdf'`

Comment: And when I comment out all stuff connected to `FreeMakerView` it show me 404 error code and for some reason redirects me to ` /pdfView` What is happening?

Comment: I added information on view-resolver configuration into the answer.